# How to add line numbers to JQ output

Tags: jq

I was curious if there is a clean way to add line numbers to `jq`'s output while still retaining the coloring of the output. I have tried piping from `jq` to `cat -n` but unfortunately this removes the coloring which helps a lot when traversing the JSON tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the jq -C option explicitly.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is to force the colors through the pipe to cat so the call would look like `jq -C . | cat -n`